# can cxf-rs return a collection of interface

Tags: rest, cxfrs

I define a interface IUser and want to return a collection of IUser as this:

   `@GET
    @Path("getuserlist/{id}/")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    List<IUser> getUserList(@PathParam("id") String id);`

When I deploy as rest service under cxf 2.7.6, I got following error:
    No message body writer has been found for response class ArrayList.
Who can help me to solve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the ArrayList in a POJO, e.g. like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SimplePOJO 
{
    private List<IUser> list;

    public List<IUser> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<IUser> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Then change your service to return the POJO class:

```
@GET 
@Path("getuserlist/{id}/") 
@Produces("application/xml") 
SimplePOJO getUserList(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

In your service implementation, all you have to do is to instantiate your SimplePOJO class and set your List of Objects implemeting your IUser interface by calling the setList() method and return the SimplePOJO class.

You might need to add the following to your IUser interface and the class implementing your IUser as well.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```